# Spring JMS Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I'm really struggling to get my Spring JMS template to work and send messages to a queue. Here's what I've got attempted:

In my XML:

```
<bean name="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="mqQueue" />
</bean>

<bean name="mqQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME}" />
    <constructor-arg value="${MQ_QUEUE_NAME}" />
</bean>

<bean name="mqQueueConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${MQ_HOST_NAME}" />
    <property name="channel" value="${MQ_CHANNEL}" />
    <property name="port" value="${MQ_PORT}" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="${MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME}" />
    <property name="transportType" ref="wmq_cl_binding" />
</bean>
```

So those are my beans for setting up the template/queue.

Now I setup a listener and `jmsContainer`:

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="CloseoutListener" />

<bean id="jmsContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="mqQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="mqQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

and my implementation of CloseoutListener is the same that is on the Spring JMS docs: [Listener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-asynchronousMessageReception)

In addition to this, I am trying to send a message in the same way that Spring sends a message in the docs: [Sender](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-sending)

**Full disclosure:** First time using queues and any sort of JMS, as well as my second time using Spring so I'm aware if this is sloppy or just plain wrong. That's why I'm asking for assistance.

No message is appearing in the queue and in addition I'm getting this message in my logs:

```
INFO  DefaultMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerSetupFailure     :825   - JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I've added some more information to the end of my message. Basically my message isn't being sent to the queue and I'm getting the above log message

Comment: Do you have the entitlements to subscribe to that MQ?

Comment: Are you sure that here: <bean id="messageListener" class="CloseoutListener" /> a full package path is not required for CloseoutListener class?

Comment: @UserF40, yes I'm positive.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov, I removed the full package path from my question to make it cleaner and to avoid including information about my company